# Cannot resolve TabListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragmentactivity, android-actionbaractivity

I am using android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity for getsupportActionbar but, after i import this"android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity" TabListener becomes cannot be resolve. I have to remove Tablistener in order get getsupportActionbar resolve.

When i try to do that
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements  ActionBar.TabListener
Fragment activity becomes undefined from which i cannot live since my whole application is built on fragment.

In simple words i want Tablistener activity with getsupportActionBar without removing it while using android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity how can it be done?

Here is my main activity:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import com.tech.slidechat.adaptor.TabsPagerAdapter;



@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBarActivity.TabListener {



private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ActionBarActivity.TabListener` interface. There is [an `ActionBar.TabListener` interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html).

Note, though, that action bar tabs were deprecated in Android 5.0 and in the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport.

Comment: When I do ActionBar.Tablistener getsupportactionbar gets unresolved

Comment: @Mustansir: `getSupportActionBar()` requires that you inherit from `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Mustansir: No, because action bar tabs are deprecated. Developers should be using some other tab solution. Beyond that, replace `MainActivity extends FragmentActivity` with `MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity`.